# Check box check state not changing at run time when form control value is changed in angular 8

Tags: angular, angular7, angular8

I have simple application which has single check box and a button. When I click the button a timer will be started and in each 1 second loop, it should change the checkbox check state to checked and un-checked.

to make sure the value of the binded formControl works properly, I have added a textbox and I've binded the same formControl(isActive) to that text box.

My problem is : value on the text box is changing repeatedly to "true" and "false" but checkbox checked state is not changing.

my app.component.html looks like this.

```
<div name="dvMain" [formGroup]="formComponents">
  <input type="text" formControlName="isActive"/>
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isActive"/>
  Active
  <button (click)="start()">Start</button>
</div>
```

my app.component.ts looks like this.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'checkbox-app';
  public formComponents : FormGroup;
  private interval;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formComponents = this.formBuilder.group({
      isActive:[false]
    });
  }

  public start():void{
    this.startTimer();
  }

  private startTimer(): void {
    let i: number = 0;
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.formComponents.patchValue({
        isActive: [i++ % 2 == 0]
      });
    }, 1000)
  }
}
```

my app.module.ts looks like this

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

please see my project in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ugu6h5?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `startTimer()`, get rid of the square brackets in `isActive: [i++ % 2 == 0]`,
your interval should work fine with: `isActive: i++ % 2 == 0` or `isActive: (i++ % 2 == 0)` if you want the brackets to make it more readable.

Also, if you also want to update the text box value when the checkbox is manually clicked, you can add change detection on the checkbox:

```
 <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isActive" (change)="onCheckChange($event)"/>
```

```
onCheckChange(e){
  this.formComponents.patchValue({
    isActive: e.target.checked
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Jojofoulk, after removing the square brackets it works as expected. Thank you for the additional details with onCheckChange() event. I'm a beginner for Angular and your answer helped a lot.